# How to place a ring using an augmented image concept

Tags: android, arcore, sceneform

I am working on an AR application in android where I have to place an ring in a finger using the augmented Image concepts.How I can achieve it and also how I surround the ring to the finger.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a comment rather than an answer but this is what one does when he doesn't have enough reputation.

I would suggest you to use ML and Image processing libraries rather than using Augmented Images.